# Raspbian путаница с groups

Tags: debian, ftp, raspbian

Запустил на raspberry FTP сервер. Делал все по гайду на сайте. Создал группу ftpgroup, создал пользователя ftpuser. Добавил основного пользователя в группу ftpgroup. Теперь: все что я создаю через FTP редактируется/удаляется только через sudo. Все, что создается системно/пользователем я не могу изменять через FTP.

Краткая сводка информации еще раз:

Группы: pi, ftpgroup

Пользователи root, ftpuser.

Пользователь root и пользователь ftpuser состоят в группах pi, ftpgroup.

Comment: а какие права на файлах и кто владелец у них?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Созданные через ssh или системно - root пользователь, созданные через ftp - ftpuser. Прав, как я понял, здесь нет. Есть `sudo chown -R ftpuser:ftpgroup /home/root/`, который приходится всегда использовать

Comment: права можно посмотреть командой la -l